# how to fetch the exclude infos from custom configuration

Tags: android, gradle

I have declared a custom configuration in build.gradle, like this:

```
...
configurations{
    offlineMerge
}

dependencies{
    offlineMerge(project(":abc")){
        exclude(group: "com.xxx.xxx", module: "test")
    }
}
...
```

the goal of the  custom configuration is merge the code of the depended local project:abc to the current project(eg. a aar module), and exclude the code of test module in the dependencies of the abc project.

so, how can I fetch the exclude info of offlineMerge, to exclude the code of test module in the custom gradle task which is used to merge the code of the project:abc by parsing the offlineMerge configuration?